Parsing large xml file from within zip archive in Powershell
I am looking for a way to parse large xml file (xml has several GB) inside zip file without deflating it first. I have zip files containing just one xml file (and nothing else), as well as zip file containing several thousands of xml files (zip file has several GB).
I thought that using streams might be a solution. This is the best construction I came up with:
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.io.compression.filesystem
$zipFile = "C:\Private\OneDrive\data\datafile.zip"
$fileName = "datafile-list.xml"
$zipContent = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::openread($zipFile)
$theFile = $zipContent.getEntry($fileName)
$streamZip = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($theFile.Open())

$f = [System.Xml.XmlTextReader]::create($streamZip)

while ($f.ReadToFollowing("box"))
{
    $box = $f.ReadSubtree()
    ... 

but I do not know how to give [System.Xml.XmlReader] proper data. Or is there other correct way?

What's wrong with what you have?

You've already supplied the reader with all the data. Now you just need to consume it:)

@Charlieface You are right. Turns out, I omitted definition of one array that is filled with data from XML.
